# How should I store a Northing, Easting Coordinate in an SQL Database?

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

My database is set up with a table of coordinate reference systems. Another table is used to store points and a foreign key is use to link these two together. What is the best way to store the point if it can either be a Northing, Easting value or a Latitude, Longitude value?

For example, should it be four separate columns (Lat, Long, Northing, Easting) where two of them will always be null? Is there a specific data type I can use for this?

I have researched the SQL geometry and geography types but do not understand how these would suit my database design.

Comment: I think nobody can really answer. It depends. When working with geographical coordinates (and other data, like times), I tend to make two tables: one "raw" with original data, and one with a format I would use in the program (so cleaned, and uniform, but we still have the old information if we need to change the base format (e.g. coordinate system/datum). (Note: both will have revisions, so expect lat,long and x,y to be different on the two tables in future.

Comment: Geometry objects are the way to go if you plan on doing anything at all spatial with the coordinates